# Creating a menu bar that height is fixed but squeezes as browser size changes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to create a menu bar that height is fixed but squeezes as browser size changes in CSS?

Here is my current CSS which is just the menu bar created in PS with the sizes 1920 X 100, I would like this to stretch the whole top of the page when browser size changes, and for height to stay the same;

```
#bar {  
background:url("/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/images/bar.png"); 
height:100px;
}
```

Thankyou very much for your help

Comment: So you want it to scale horizontally but not vertically? Wouldn't this make the image look strange as its aspect ratio would be off?

Comment: Hi, yes i would like it to scale just horizontally because this is just a menu bar that currently is just a block colour saved as a PNG from photoshop. Thanks for nay help

Comment: @bjbear123 why don't repeat the image horizontally then?

Comment: If it is just a block of color, why not make it easier by simply using `background-color:#whatever;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the property `background-size` you make your container be `width:100%` as behave default divs and the background always 100% :

```
#bar {  
  background:url("/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/images/bar.png") no-repeat center; 
  height:100px;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/RLPbg/.

<sub>[About compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)</sub>

The problem here is your image is been distorted.

**Edit**

Remember ir your image is just a png color you alwasy can use other options like:

- Repeat background.
- Linear Gradients

Comment: This is perfect thank you, is there a way i can compress the image vertically, instead of using height:100px where half the image is cut off?